# generating a numeric hash for a string in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to generate a unique TCP port number for a given string (I need this to mock a response from a server, unique for each string).

I want to use a string parameter as a source for this port number. In other words, I need to generate a numeric hash in a given range (1000-32767) from an arbitrary string.

I can do this in Python with no issues, but I don't know how to do it in Ansible.

Is there any way to generate a stable numeric in range hash from a string in Ansible?

An example of a play:

```
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
     - debug: msg="Hash for {{ item }} is {{ item |HELP_ME_HERE }}"
       with_items:
        - string1
        - string_two
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to generate a stable numeric in range hash from a string in Ansible?

```yaml
 - set_fact:
     r: "{{ range(1000, 37272) | random(seed=item) }}"
   run_once: yes
   loop:
     - string

 - debug:
     msg: "{{ r }}"
```

Comment: wow. It's a clever idea. I made it by using last for hexdigits of md5...

Comment: Is this possible in C#?

Comment: C# is a way different tool than Ansible. It's most likely possible in C#, I just don't know how.